# conditionally change django template variable

Tags: django, django-templates

### tl;dr

I need a template variable to change by concatenating strings along the way.

### my issue

I'm looping through a queryset in my template, and inside the loop I'm checking if certain fields on the object match the current `user`. If so, then my variable changes and is finally applied as a `class` to an element.

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% with class="" %}
        {% if request.user == item.field1 %}
            /* append to class variable, ex: class=" field1" */
        {% endif %}
        {% if request.user == item.field2 %}
            /* append to class variable, ex: class=" field1 field2" */
        {% endif %}

        <div class="{{class}}"></div>
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

So, if my `request.user` equals both `item.field1` and `item.field2` then my element would look like this:

```
<div class=" field1 field2"></div>
```

And if my `request.user` equals only `item.field2` then my element would look like this:

```
<div class=" field2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in Django template language. You could potentially write a tag, but I don't see why you would want to; you can just do the whole thing inline.

```
<div class="{% if request.user == item.field1 %}field1{% endif %} {% if request.user == item.field2 %}field2{% endif %}"></div>
```

Comment: It was actually an `include` tag that I was passing the class into, not a `div`. That's why I didn't do it inline. I'll just have to change what I was doing to do it this way.